# hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map lookup error

Tags: postfix

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on Google Cloud Compute. After completing [this tutorial on 
sending Email with SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), I am getting an error when testing sendgrid in command line:

```
- server3 postfix/trivial-rewrite[15407]: warning:
  hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map lookup error for
  "user@server3.<mydomain>.com.au"

server3 postfix/trivial-rewrite[15407]: warning:
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps lookup failure

server3 postfix/error[17434]: B62708488F: to=<recipient@gmail.com>,
relay=none, delay=0.24, delays=0.2/0.02/0/0.02, dsn=4.3.0,
status=deferred (address resolver failure)
```

Now if I look at this and try to apply some logic to it, I believe that the problem is there is no `relayhost_map` for my `user@server3.<mydomain>.com.au`?

Is the relay map missing for the server, or for the user? I seem to get the same error no matter which user I am sending a test email with (I have tried 3 of them that are active).

I am not sure what to do to fix this?

Comment: Possible, problem in your email address: try to change to 'user@server3.com.au'

Comment: Also, postfix can't detect local address for domain server3..com.au and try to relay mail, then can't find server3..com.au in relay maps and try to contact directly, but no A or MX records configured in DNS.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out what the problem is. This is an important change that needs to be made in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.
You must ensure that if it exists, the following line is commented out or deleted...

```
#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
```

If that line is not commented out, obviously postfix goes looking for a `relayhost_map` (which does not exist if the tutorials are followed).

Hope this helps someone else... the google cloud tutorial on this is incomplete, as is the sendgrid one.